# "And" function not checking that both criteria are met

Tags: vba, excel

Relatively new to using VBA (and coding in general) but I can't for the life of me understand why this isn't working.

I want a different output to occur based on what two options are selected in the combo boxes within my Userform.

The "WHY GOD WHY" generation occurs if `oindex` = 1 no matter what value `index` is.

```
Private Sub SubmitButton_Click()

Dim oindex As Integer
oindex = Output.ListIndex

If (index = 0 And oindex = 1) Then
   Range("A7").Value = "WHY GOD WHY"
    End If

Unload UserForm

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With Demand
    .AddItem "I want policy details"
    .AddItem "I would like a value"
    .AddItem "I want to cancel my policy"
    .AddItem "I want to change my address"
    .AddItem "I would like Surrender Forms"
    .AddItem "I would like to update my bank details"
    .AddItem "I want to make an alteration on my policy"
    .AddItem "I want to transfer my plan"
    .AddItem "I have a fund query"
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub Demand_Change()

Dim index As Integer
index = Demand.ListIndex

Output.Clear

Select Case index
    Case Is >= 0
        With Output
            .AddItem "I need to provide this information verbally"
            .AddItem "I need to update/send this myself"
            .AddItem "I need to ask back-office to update/send this"
        End With


End Select

End Sub
```

Hopefully you might be able to help out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scope.

```
Private Sub Demand_Change()
Dim index As Integer
```

Here `index` is local to`Demand_Change()`, accessing it outside of that sub as you do in `SubmitButton_Click()` will not provide the value, but will be treated as zero.

Instead declare it as `private index as integer` at the top of the module.

Comment: Alex & I came up with the same solution, but I've got to say, David Zemens' would be the best way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't have an `Option Explicit` shown, and you don't show where `index` is declared, I would assume that in this subroutine, `index` is getting created on the fly:

```
Private Sub SubmitButton_Click()
  Dim oindex As Integer
  oindex = Output.ListIndex
  If (index = 0 And oindex = 1) Then
    Range("A7").Value = "WHY GOD WHY"
  End If
  Unload UserForm
End Sub
```

Since `index` is never assigned a value, it remains at its default value of 0.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, work with your objects directly. I don't think there's any need to use module-scoped variable:

```
Private Sub SubmitButton_Click()

If (Me.Demand.ListIndex = 0 And Me.Output.ListIndex = 1) Then
   Range("A7").Value = "WHY GOD WHY"
End If

Unload UserForm

End Sub
```

The reason for this is that you already have a handle on those *values*, in the form controls themselves.  Using module- or public-scoped variables will technically *work*, but can become harder to manage and trace errors or debug, and it's also redundant.

If you are working with those values, in the `SubmitButton_Click` subroutine multiple times and want to use *variables* for brevity, then do it at the procedure level:

```
Private Sub SubmitButton_Click()
Dim dIndex as Integer, oIndex as Integer
dIndex = Me.Demand.ListIndex
oIndex = Me.Output.ListIndex

If (dIndex = 0 And oIndex = 1) Then
   Range("A7").Value = "WHY GOD WHY"
End If

Unload UserForm

End Sub
```